# Ajax Posts but does not call Django View

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

### The Problem

*After posting to my django view, the code seems to just stop halfway through.*

I have an ajax post to a Django view that is hard coded to render a specific response (see below). When I post to that view it should always return that response, but for some reason 
the view out puts all of the print statements, but not the query or the render. I know I'm being redirected by my sever log (shown below).

**Any idea what could be causing this behavior?**

Server log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Aug/2013 21:27:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Aug/2013 21:27:23] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Aug/2013 21:27:23] "GET /static/js/map.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Aug/2013 21:27:23] "GET /static/js/home_jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Aug/2013 21:27:23] "GET /static/js/jquery_cookie/jquery.cookie.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Aug/2013 21:27:23] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
I've been posted. Here are my values
<QueryDict: {u'name': [u'Mission Chinese Food'], u'address': [u'154 Orchard Street Manhattan']}>
Mission Chinese Food
154 Orchard Street Manhattan
Fish
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Aug/2013 21:27:32] "POST /results/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Simple Django View:

```
def results(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "I've been posted. Here are my values"
        print request.POST
        print request.POST.get('name')
        print request.POST.get('address')
    restaurant = Restaurant.objects.filter(name='Fish', address='280 Bleecker St')[0]
    print restaurant
    return render(request, "stamped/restaurant.html", {'restaurant': restaurant}
```

Simple ajax post:

```
var send_data = { 'name': place.name, 'address': address};

    var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken'); 

    alert(csrftoken);
    alert(send_data);

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    } 

    $.ajaxSetup({
        crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });

    $.ajax({ url: '/results/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: send_data,
        success: function(response) {
          console.log("everything worked!");
        },
        error: function(obj, status, err) { alert(err); console.log(err); }
      });




  });
```

Comment: Do you want to render the result, or just display the console.log line?  Try .submit()-ing a form instead of $.ajax, if you want to display the HTML from stamped/restaurant.html in your browser as the full page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using:

```
$.ajax({ url: '/results/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: send_data,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log("everything worked!");
      $("#results").html(response);
    },
    error: function(obj, status, err) { alert(err); console.log(err); }
  });
```

I was trying to use Django to redirect me to the render response like it ussually does. Because I'm calling from javascript to response is redriceted to javascript and the the typical django functions.

This part of the function

```
  success: function(response) {
          $("#results").html(response);
        },
```

renders the response to my chosen results div.